# Error with the htaccess and htpasswd files in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter-3, .htpasswd

I should protect only one Controller file with htaccess and htpasswd.
I entered these instructions in the htaccess file, but I get an 'Internal Server Error' error.
The .htaccess file and the .htpasswd file are located outside the application folder.

```
<Files ControllerFile>
AuthName "ControllerFile"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
```

Thanks, ciao

Comment: Where did you place your htaccess?  in most cases should be above your site dir.

Comment: The .htaccess and .htpasswd files are located in the main folder of the site

Comment: Try to set it in your www folder above your site folder.